# IValueConverter set new image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, visual-studio-2010, ivalueconverter

Hi to all out there...

I facing one problem which is cannot set the new image:

Does my code correct?

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {

            var str = value.ToString();

            if (str == "income")
                return new BitmapImage(new Uri("/images/add.png", UriKind.Relative));

            if (str == "Expenses")
            {

                return new BitmapImage(new Uri("/HouseWivesSavior;component/images/add.png"));
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: May be your image path is not correct.

Comment: Check below Url. It will give you an  idea how to do it.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204883/wpf-imagesource-binding-with-custom-converter

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the image files have their `Build Action` set to `Resource` as shown for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14925269/1136211). Then you would have to properly create their [Pack URIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx), like

```
return new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/images/add.png"));
```

and

```
return new BitmapImage(
    new Uri("pack://application:,,,/HouseWivesSavior;component/images/add.png"));
```

Comment: #Clemens, Thank for your answer & it is totally right :) As now I can retrieve my image for now. I will post my solution so that when other facing same problem will have a idea in solving it :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my answer which is the format of the string. Which causing me to unavailable to retrieve the image with few hours of troubleshooting & debugging. I finally found out the solution :)

I solve it by like this:In my converter.cs

public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{

```
string str = (string)value;
string newString = str.TrimEnd();//Newly added compared with the old version

if (newString == "income")
   return new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/images/add.png"));

if (newString == "Expenses")
{
    //return new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/HouseWivesSavior;component/images/add.png"));
    return new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/images/edit.png"));
}

return null;
```

}

From referring the above that you can see that I added this code:
"string newString = str.TrimEnd();"

Is because I don't want extra white space at the end of the string. As during insert into the database that my code is look like this:

```
   if (IncomeButton.IsChecked == true) {
                    CategoryType = IncomeButton.Content.ToString();
                }else{
                    CategoryType = ExpensesButton.Content.ToString();
                }
```

During runtime, I found out that why the value look strange in the format of "Expenses " instead of "Expenses"... Therefore I tried with trim of the end part see how & Bingo. I got it working like a charm.

I refered this video to out that how to trace the value: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=evO3_xutDYI

Thank you all guys for answering my question & sorry for wasting your time & effort to solve my question :) Good luck to all of you & have a nice day.